# Javascript API Fetch make a filter PokeApi

Tags: javascript, pokeapi

I´m studying Javascript. And for that I am making a Pokémon Game based on the PokéAPI

To make it simple, I want to retrieve - filter - Pokémons with types Fire, Water & Grass.

[image]

I understand I should go to data > types > (look in the slots 1 & 2) > search for grass, fire & water.

So this is my code, so far, and I was thinking if I could do it BEFORE retrieving the data to the API. Otherwise I´ll have to retrieve EVERY Pokémon and then filter them.

```js
const baseUrl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=150'
try {
    fetch(baseUrl)
        .then(response => {
            const responseJson = response.json()
            return responseJson
        })

    .then(async data => {
        const pokemons = data.results


        for (const pokemon of pokemons) {
            pokemon.data = await fetch(pokemon.url).then(res => res.json())
        }



        console.log(pokemons)
    })

    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
    })
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not normalize the API data you have to filter using this list. But when you get the pokemon list you can normalize the list to a more friendly structure to your app.

```js
function normalizeList (item = {}) {
  const { name, data } = item
   // Define your normalized data here

  return {
    name,
    types: data.types
  }
}
```

If you need to transform/parse or whatever I recomend you to create a PokemonModel and create Pokemon Class instances:

```js
class PokemonModel {
  constructor(data = {}) {
    this.name = data.name
    this.types = this._getTypes(data.types)
  }

  _getTypes(types = []) {
    return types.map((type) => {
      return {
        name: type.name
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Your code with PokemonModel:

```js
class PokemonModel {
  constructor(data = {}) {
    this.name = data.name
    this.types = this._getTypes(data.types)
  }

  _getTypes(types = []) {
    return types.map((type) => {
      return {
        name: type.name
      }
    })
  }
}

const baseUrl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=150'
const pokemonList = []

try {
  fetch(baseUrl)
    .then(response => {
      const responseJson = response.json()
      return responseJson
    })

  .then(async data => {
    const pokemons = data.results

    for (const pokemon of pokemons) {
      pokemon.data = await fetch(pokemon.url).then(res => res.json())
      pokemonList.push(new PokemonModel(pokemon.data))
    }
    console.log(pokemonList)
  })

  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I´ll research more about your answer, because I still don´t understand it! But surely will work on it!!! Thnanks!